# Eq or Ord instances for existential GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt, existential-type

Is there a convenient way to get an instance of `Ord` (or `Eq`) to compare any two values of a GADT, irrespective of the type parameter.

In the GADT, the type parameter is phantom, just meant to associate each constructor with a type, e.g. the GADT represent keys/queries, and the type parameter is the type of the associated value/result.

To illustrate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, Rank2Types #-}

data Car = Car   -- whatever
data Food = Food

data CarRental  = CarRental  {passengers :: Int, mileage :: Int}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
data ErrandList = ErrandList {avoidJunkFood :: Bool}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data GetStuff a where
  RentACar :: CarRental  -> GetStuff Car
  BuyFood  :: ErrandList -> GetStuff Food

data Some t = forall a. Some (t a)
```

`GetStuff` is a GADT, so that each item is associated with a result type, `Car` or `Food`. I can use that in e.g `Free` or `FreeApplicative`. I may want to retrieve all the GetStuff that appear in the structure. I can easily build `[Some GetStuff]`, but not a `Set (Some GetStuff)`, for lack of an Ord instance.

I see that

```
data GetSomeStuff = RentSomeCar CarRental | BuySomeFood ErrandList
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

is isomorphic to `Some GetStuff` (`a` is phantom in GetStuff), so I can get Eq, Ord, and possibly others by writing this isomorphism:

```
existentialToUntyped :: Some GetStuff -> GetSomeStuff
untypedToExistential :: GetSomeStuff -> Some GetStuff

untypedToExistential (RentSomeCar x) = Some $ RentACar x
untypedToExistential (BuySomeFood x) = Some $ BuyFood x
existentialToUntyped (Some (RentACar x)) = RentSomeCar x
existentialToUntyped (Some (BuyFood x)) = BuySomeFood x
```

but it's tedious for protocols much larger than GetStuff. Is there a better way, with or without GADT?

Also, I intend to write code parametric in the "protocol" type (here GetStuff) at this point, where I would like a signature such as

```
queries :: SomeConstraint protocol => 
  FreeApplicative protocol 
  -> Set (Some protocol)
```

I may have to do

```
myFunction :: Ord untyped => 
  Iso (Some protocol, untyped) 
  -> FreeApplicative protocol
  -> Set untyped
```

Again, is there a better way?

Comment: Strictly speaking, `GetSomeStuff` is only isomorphic to `sigma a. GetStuff a` (a type which doesn’t exist in Haskell). In particular note that `[GetSomeStuff]` and `[GetStuff a]` are not isomorphic. Alternatively, consider that no halting function of type `GetSomeStuff -> GetStuff a` exists.

Comment: @DanRobertson I meant between (Some GetStuff) and GetSomeStuff. I added an implementation above, it feels ok to me, but I'm just getting my feet wet here. Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your example

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Type.Equality

data Car
data Food

data CarRental  = CarRental  {passengers :: Int, mileage :: Int}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
data ErrandList = ErrandList {avoidJunkFood :: Bool}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data GetStuff a where
  RentACar :: CarRental  -> GetStuff Car
  BuyFood  :: ErrandList -> GetStuff Food

data Some t = forall a. Some (t a)
```

You'll need to write an instance of
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dependent-sum-0.4/docs/Data-GADT-Compare.html#t:GEq

```hs
class GEq f where
  geq :: f a -> f b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
```

Then you'll be able to define an instance of `Eq (Some f)`

```hs
instance GEq f => Eq (Some f) where
    Some fa == Some fb = case geq fa fb of
        Just Refl -> True
        Nothing   -> False
```

Writing an instance by hand is repetitive, but not awful.
Note that I wrote in the way without "catch all" last case.

```hs
instance GEq GetStuff where
  geq (RentACar x) z = case z of
    RentACar x' -> if x == x' then Just Refl else Nothing
    _           -> Nothing

  geq (BuyFood x) z = case z of
    BuyFood x' -> if x == x' then Just Refl else Nothing
    _          -> Nothing
```

There's a `GCompare` class for `Ord` of GADTs.

So the problem reduces to "how to derive `GEq` or `GCompare` automatically".
I think that for special GADTs, like your `GetStuff`, you can
write quick-n-dirty TH, to generate the code.

`Generic`-like alternative I can think of would require you to
write conversion functions from and to `GetStuff`, which
might be a win if you need to write more generic functions.
Let's explore that too. First we define a generic representation
of GADTs we are interested in:

```hs
data Sum (cs :: [(*, *)]) a where
  Z :: a :~: c -> b -> Sum ( '(c, b) ': cs) a
  S :: Sum cs a -> Sum (c ': cs) a
```

We can convert between `GetStuff` and `Sum`.
That we'll need to write for each GADT, this is *O(n)* where `n` is constructors count.

```hs
type GetStuffCode =
  '[ '(Car, CarRental)
  ,  '(Food, ErrandList)
  ]

toSum :: GetStuff a -> Sum GetStuffCode a
toSum (RentACar x) = Z Refl x
toSum (BuyFood x)  = S (Z Refl x)

fromSum :: Sum GetStuffCode a -> GetStuff a
fromSum (Z Refl x)     = RentACar x
fromSum (S (Z Refl x)) = BuyFood x
fromSum (S (S x))      = case x of {} -- silly GHC requires this :)
```

Now, as we have generic representation, `Sum`, we can write generic
functions. Equality, `GGEq` for *Generic Gadt Equality*
The class looks like `GEq`, but we use `Sum` as an arguments.

```hs
class GGEq code where
  ggeq :: Sum code a -> Sum code b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
```

We'll need two instances, for nil and cons *codes*:

```hs
instance GGEq '[] where
  ggeq x _ = case x of {}

instance (Eq b, '(x, b) ~ c, GGEq cs) => GGEq (c ': cs) where
  ggeq (Z Refl x) (Z Refl y) = if x == y then Just Refl else Nothing
  ggeq (S x)      (S y)      = ggeq x y

  ggeq (Z _ _) (S _)   = Nothing
  ggeq (S _)  (Z _ _) = Nothing
```

Using that machinery, writing `geq` for `GetStuff` is trivial:

```hs
geq1 :: GetStuff a -> GetStuff b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
geq1 x y = ggeq (toSum x) (toSum y)
```

Comment: Thank you. Quite a lot to digest, and quite a lot to learn to. Feels like using all the extensions at once.

Comment: @DidierDupont that's usual collection of extenesions if one want to use `DataKinds` (for type-level lists in this answer). I can amend the answer with explanation of them, if it would help

Comment: Not to worry, I see what most of them are related to, and the extensions' documentation is ok. Nice to have a list of interesting thing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Support for this looks to have improved over the years. You can now use `Some` from the `Data.Some` module, rather than defining your own. That will provide `Eq` and `Ord` instances automatically, provided your GADT has `GEq` and `GCompare` instances. You can use `deriveGEq` and `deriveGCompare` from the Data.GADT.Compare.TH module to generate the `GEq` and `GCompare` instances.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs,
    StandaloneDeriving,
    TemplateHaskell #-}
    
import Data.Some
import Data.GADT.Compare.TH
import Data.Set

data Car = Car
data Food = Food

data CarRental  = CarRental  {passengers :: Int, mileage :: Int}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
data ErrandList = ErrandList {avoidJunkFood :: Bool}
  deriving (Eq, Ord)

data GetStuff a where
  RentACar :: CarRental  -> GetStuff Car
  BuyFood  :: ErrandList -> GetStuff Food

deriving instance Eq (GetStuff a)
deriving instance Ord (GetStuff a)

deriveGEq ''GetStuff
deriveGCompare ''GetStuff

list2set :: [Some GetStuff] -> Set (Some GetStuff)
list2set = fromList
```